# File Upload Plugin/Development approach for handling json responses

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

My question is not really an issue, more a development approach. Apologies if I am posting here and not the support forum as in my workplace they block https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jquery-fileupload.

I have read alot of the documentation around content type negotiation and handling json response for xhr requests and iframe.

On the server side, i have feature detection to check if the request is ajax or not. If it is not, then i return a response with content-type **text/html;charset=UTF-8**.

Now on the client side, I was deciding how to parse the json object. I assumed that the response returned in IE8 was the json object, but that is not the case. So in my done callback I check if the datatype is iframe or not.

Can you please verify if the javascript I have defined below is valid please? The below client side logic works for me on **IE8 and on Firefox 28.0**.

My sample json response is:

```
{"result":"Files  uploaded successfully"}

done: function (e, data) {
            if($.trim(data.dataType) == "iframe"){
                var result = JSON.parse(data.result[0].body.innerHTML);
            } else{
                 var result =  data.result;
            }
                $('<p/>').text('Server side response: ' + result.result).appendTo(".files" );

            });
        },
```

Comment: If it works then it's valid. However, that's not the same as having it work in every browser. You need to determine what your target audience is using and what you're going to support and test for that.

Comment: As i said above, it works. On the server side i use feature detection, not browser detection which is correct. Either the plugin posts an xhr request or iframe transport. My question is on the client side. Is this how you handle successful callback?

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault.

I was using the basic plugin which does not specify the datatype. When i specify the datatype to json i do not need that condition on the client side.